# Recursively Split String on Delimter

Tags: python, string, substring

I am trying to split a string by a delimiter recursively. I'm currently doing it with a for loop but there maybe a more pythonic way I'm not aware about, possibly using list comprehension.

```
splits = []
my_string = 'partA_partB_partC_partD'
count = my_string.count('_')

for i in range(count):
    my_string = my_string.rsplit('_',1)[0]
    splits.append(my_string)
```

Edit: One reason I think there is a better solution is that `i` is never used.

Expected Result

`['partA_partB_partC', 'partA_partB', 'partA']`

Comment: Why do you need to do this in a `for` loop? Use `split`: `my_string.split("_")` returns a `list` with four elements.

Comment: That will return ```['partA', 'partB', 'partC', 'partD']``` which is not what I am looking for. If I did that, I would have to loop through and build the combined result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for recursion. Just split to an array and join back together:

```
my_string = 'partA_partB_partC_partD'
parts = my_string.split('_')
result = ['_'.join(parts[:i]) for i in range(len(parts) - 1, 0, -1)]
print(result)
```

```
['partA_partB_partC', 'partA_partB', 'partA']
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

An alternative iterative approach (though less Pythonic than @AKX's IMO) is:

```
splits = []
my_string = 'partA_partB_partC_partD'

first = True

while True:
    try:
        part, _ = (my_string if first else part).rsplit("_", 1)
        if first:
            first = False
    except ValueError:  # If we catch this, we can't split, so stop.
        break

    splits.append(part)
```